# Flutter: How do you set the text color for a ListTile that is 'selected'?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter app where I am using a drawer. The drawer consists of various menu options using the ListTile class. The documentation specifies that when the 'selected' property of a ListTile is true then 'By default the selected color is the theme's primary color.' but it makes no mention of the text color. Whenever a ListTile is selected the corresponding text changes to blue, which goes against my theme. How do I set the text color for a selected ListTile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply theme to ListTile by wrapping it with [ListTileTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTileTheme-class.html).

```
ListTileTheme(
        selectedColor: Colors.red, // text & icon color
        selectedTileColor: Colors.green, // background color
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text('cats')
        )
)
```